# Bidimensional array in PHP cant acces nominatim geocoding data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, geocoding, nominatim

I'm accessing lat and lon via nominatim json and converting it to php array,all the stuff works until i try to acces lon into one array. If i acces to the array int its ok but if i try to get what's inside it dont.

```
$url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/".$_GET['places']."?format=json&email=gotia.ts@gmai.com";
$placeJSON = file_get_contents($url);
$arrPlace = json_decode($placeJSON);

//$lati = $arrPlace[0]; works

//That does not
$lati = $arrPlace[0]['lat'];
```

Comment: change `json_decode($placeJSON);` to `json_decode($placeJSON, true);`

Comment: You're my hero mate !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You Try this format

```
echo $lati = $arrPlace['0']->lat;
```

Working fine